# mixing $in and $or mongo search operations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Folks,
  I am trying to mix `$all` and `$nin` mongodb 2.6 query parameters.  Is mixing `$or` with `$all` and `$nin` allowed in such manner?

Essentially what we are trying to retrieve here, are documents that either have `['foo','bar']`... `OR` that dont have `['baz']`

query:

```
{
    "_type": {
        "$in": [
            "A"
        ]
    },
    "tags": {
        "$or": [
            {
                "$all": [
                    "foo","bar"
                ]
            },
            {
                "$nin": [
                    "baz"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

error:

```
HCError: (HCError) error converting cursor to array | caused by: MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $or
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) does not act on the field at it's parent, but rather expects an entire "query document" as it's child:

```js
{
    "_type": {
        "$in": [
            "A"
        ]
    },
    "$or": [
        { "tags": { "$all": [ "foo","bar"] } },
        { "tags": { "$nin": [ "baz" ] } }
    ]
}
```